# How can I get a date into this format, 2013-08-09T19:08:28Z?

Tags: php, date, datetime

In a table I need to get some information from, the created_at and updated_at columns were wrongly defined as VARCHAR and not as a timestamp. Therefore, I need to pass the date as a string in my query.

I need to obtain a date in this format:

```
2013-08-09T19:08:28Z
```

I would prefer to use the `DateTime` class in PHP.

Comment: Will the timezone always be `Z` (i.e. UTC/GMT)? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: The timezone will never change. It's not my DB and that's how they store it. I just need this format to query through SOAP. I tried any option with DateTime and nothing works. It only works when I pass the date in this format: 2013-08-09T19:08:28Z, with the Z at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally specify the [format string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) with the literal `Z`:

```
$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```

Comment: ... but only if the value is already in UTC.  It would be invalid to put a `Z` at the end otherwise.

Comment: @MattJohnson Duly noted. Code modified to ensure that instantiated time is in UTC/GMT.

Answer (score 2):

you use need to use the `c` qualifier

```
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->format('c');
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, your code gives me this: 2013-08-17T05:39:49+00:00. I need this: 2013-08-09T19:08:28Z

Comment: @user1336449 - Those are equivalent representations by the ISO8601 standard. You should be able to use that anywhere you would expect to pass the `Z`.

Comment: You're right Matt, but if the column was set as a string data type in the database and not as a timestamp, I have to pass it as text. Like I said, it's not my database. I'm just using it.